# Different query plan for GROUP BY DISTINCT query on 2 distinct machines

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run the same query on two databases running on separate machines. And I am trying to find the setting/settings that causes them to use different query plans.

SETUP

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    condition_id BIGINT,
    group_by_id BIGINT,
    order_date DATE,
    data DOUBLE PRECISION
);

INSERT INTO my_table (condition_id, group_by_id, order_date, data)
SELECT 1000 * random(),
       10000 * random(),
       current_date - cast(cast(100 * random() AS BIGINT) || ' day' AS INTERVAL),
       random()
FROM generate_series(1, 10000000);

CREATE INDEX my_table_idx ON my_table (condition_id, group_by_id, order_date DESC);

VACUUM ANALYSE my_table;
```

QUERY

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_by_id) *
FROM my_table
    WHERE condition_id = 1
ORDER BY group_by_id, order_date DESC;
```

RESULTS

MACHINE 1 UNCACHED

```
Unique  (cost=0.56..10220.12 rows=6209 width=28) (actual time=0.034..8.820 rows=6393 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=10106 read=54
  I/O Timings: read=0.367
  ->  Index Scan using my_table_idx on my_table  (cost=0.56..10195.97 rows=9662 width=28) (actual time=0.033..6.935 rows=10106 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (condition_id = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=10106 read=54
        I/O Timings: read=0.367
Planning time: 0.177 ms
Execution time: 9.197 ms
```

MACHINE 1 CACHED

```
Unique  (cost=0.56..10220.12 rows=6209 width=28) (actual time=0.013..9.059 rows=6393 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=10160
  ->  Index Scan using my_table_idx on my_table  (cost=0.56..10195.97 rows=9662 width=28) (actual time=0.013..7.245 rows=10106 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (condition_id = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=10160
Planning time: 0.069 ms
Execution time: 9.430 ms
```

MACHINE 2 UNCACHED

```
Unique  (cost=10261.82..10271.81 rows=6319 width=28) (actual time=3604.888..3607.945 rows=6243 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=9236
  I/O Timings: read=3186.548
  ->  Sort  (cost=10261.82..10266.81 rows=9987 width=28) (actual time=3604.886..3606.016 rows=9808 loops=1)
        Sort Key: group_by_id, order_date DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1151kB
        Buffers: shared read=9236
        I/O Timings: read=3186.548
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=70.59..10129.13 rows=9987 width=28) (actual time=29.201..3528.437 rows=9808 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (condition_id = 1)
              Heap Blocks: exact=9184
              Buffers: shared read=9236
              I/O Timings: read=3186.548
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_table_idx  (cost=0.00..70.09 rows=9987 width=0) (actual time=27.637..27.637 rows=9808 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (condition_id = 1)
                    Buffers: shared read=52
                    I/O Timings: read=2.168
Planning time: 0.771 ms
Execution time: 3608.721 ms
```

MACHINE 2 CACHED

```
Unique  (cost=10261.82..10271.81 rows=6319 width=28) (actual time=32.859..40.082 rows=6243 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=9236
  ->  Sort  (cost=10261.82..10266.81 rows=9987 width=28) (actual time=32.856..36.278 rows=9808 loops=1)
        Sort Key: group_by_id, order_date DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1151kB
        Buffers: shared hit=9236
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on my_table  (cost=70.59..10129.13 rows=9987 width=28) (actual time=2.884..26.122 rows=9808 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (condition_id = 1)
              Heap Blocks: exact=9184
              Buffers: shared hit=9236
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on my_table_idx  (cost=0.00..70.09 rows=9987 width=0) (actual time=1.551..1.551 rows=9808 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (condition_id = 1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=52
Planning time: 0.098 ms
Execution time: 40.907 m
```

They are running different hardware and slightly different postgres versions. Machine 1 is running 10.10 while Machine 2 is running 10.6. Next step for me is probably to try and upgrade the version on both machines.

I've tried changing work_mem, random_page_cost, effective_cache_size and cpu_tuple_cost. But that doesn't seem to affect it (if I don't set it to something silly which cause them both to behave worse). Setup on both machines when running above test was:

```
work_mem 20971kB
random_page_cost 1.1
effective_cache_size 24GB
cpu_tuple_cost 0.01
```

I believe that I want Machine 2 to run the same query plan as Machine 1. Because as is it now 2 is heavily affected by how the data is ordered on disc and whether the data is in memory or not.

It turned out the query plans weren't all that different. Just that Machine 1 just kept it in cache forever. To actually make the reads reasonable when it's not cached I will probably try to cluster it from time to time. And maybe instead look over why machine 2 uncaches the table so often.

```
CLUSTER my_table USING my_table_idx;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question - just out of curiosity: why `generate_series(-5000000, 5000000)` and not `generate_series(1, 10000000)`?

Comment: A shot in the dark: what is the value of `enable_indexscan` on machine 2?

Comment: generate series choice is not relevant for the question. But I can update it for clarity. enable_indexscan is on for both machines.

Comment: I know that's not relevant, no need to change it. I am just curious why you prefer to write the range in that way `(-x/2, x/2)` and not the "traditional way" `(1,x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two plans have almost the same estimated cost, so it could be randomness. Remember that you used `random()` to generate data. Does the plan remain stable per machine across several test runs?

The observed difference may well be a caching effect. The slow plan performs a lot of I/O, while the fast plan had everything cached.

To get even more from your execution plans, set `track_io_timing` to `on`.

Configuration parameters that influence the plan choice here are `effective_cache_size` (high valurs favor index scans) and `random_page_cost` (low values favor index scans).

Comment: This has also been tried on the same dataset. Which gave the same difference in query plan. It was just a quick way to give a vague id of how the data looked (and the random one produced the same result as when trying with the same dataset this one time). Yes it seems like it is the I/O that takes time. But I'm trying to figure out why one of them always (?) seem to be reading from disc while the other never (?) does. Setting track_io_timing to on didn't seem to give me any more output on either machine?

Comment: Did you reload? With `track_io_timings`, you will see every I/O accompanied by a line like `I/O Timings: read=0.339` which tells you the time spent doing I/O.

Comment: I ran pg_reload_conf() but I guess it's still probably true that it just didn't reload properly. I will try restarting the db with a new conf file tomorrow and see if that works better.

Comment: Saying that one always seems to be reading from disc and the other not in the first comment is also pretty inaccurate of me. But one always performs a Bitmap Heap Scan and the other an Index Scan. I.e. they always seem to have the same difference in query plan.

Comment: Right, but is the execution time also different if everything is in cache?

Comment: The I/O Timings are large for the one doing the Bitmap Index Scan (2) when the data is not in cache. But the reason I didn't see any Timings yesterday was that both was only reading from cache when I tried. I will update the outputs with uncached vs cached output with I/O timings in the original post.

Comment: So the difference is almost exclusively I/O. Note that your "machine 1 uncached" plan is not really uncached - it only reads 54 blocks. I think the plans really are pretty equivalent.

Comment: I added something about the relevant parameters to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you're correct. I managed to replicate it on machine 1 now. I guess the difference in how the query plans look is just down to postgres version then?

Comment: The version is the same, so that shouldn't be the difference. Did you compare thr parameters I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, as stated already in the original post. effective_cache_size and random_page cost was the same on both machines. Experimenting with them was pretty much where I started but it didn't get me anywhere. I'm still a little puzzled from the difference in outputs. But verifying that the table was actually cached on M2 for all of my queries was enough to progress.